# What am I missing in Masked Input Plugin (jquery) to function, for a phone number validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I had this working in prototype.js but it conflicted with a few script files. This is how I set it up in the new script using http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

  jQuery(function($){
  $("#phone").mask("(999)999-9999");
  $.mask.definitions['~']='[+-]';
  $("#eyescript").mask("~9.99 ~9.99 999");
  });

</script>
```

This is obviously missing something based on my script in prototype.js, here is an example I had to remove.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/system/js/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/system/js/prototype.maskedinput.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {

    new MaskedInput('#phone', '(999)999-9999');

    new MaskedInput('#eyescript', '~9.99 ~9.99 999', {
        completed: function(){
            alert("You typed the following: " + this.getValue());
        }
    });

    MaskedInput.definitions['~']='[+-]';

    new MaskedInput('#eyescript2', '~9.99 ~9.99 999', {
        completed: function(){
            alert("You typed the following: " + this.getValue());
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Like I said, this script did work but gave me conflicts with too many thing (mootools/jquery) so I want to make the jquery version work for this action instead and see if it resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working with this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
  jQuery(function($) {
  $.mask.definitions['~']='[+-]';
  $('#phone').mask('(999)999-9999');
  $("#product").mask("a*-999-a999",{placeholder:" ",completed:function(){alert("You typed the following: "+this.val());}});
  $("#eyescript").mask("~9.99 ~9.99 999");
   });
// ]]&gt;</script>
```